# Causing a synthetic event passed from a function to change MUI select in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, render

I have a select that shows a configuration for a classroom seating chart.  I want it to update to the newest configuration when a new seating chart is created.  Here's the select:

```
<FormControl fullWidth variant="filled" >
                <InputLabel id="configuration-select-label">Current Group Seating Chart</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="configuration-select-label"
                  id="configuration-select"
                  value={seatingConfig.name}
                  defaultValue={startingConfig}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChangeConfig(e)}
                >
                { seatingConfig.map((name, index) => (
                  <MenuItem key={index} value={name}>
                    <Typography variant='inherit' noWrap>{name}</Typography>
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
```

and here are the functions for handling the select change / creating a new seating chart:

```
const handleChangeConfig = async (e) => {
    let tempCurrent = ''
    const tempStudent =studentInfo;
    // console.log(e)
    // console.log(e.target.value)
    try{
      const discussionGroups = await axios.get('/api/discussionGroups', {
        params: { configuration: e.target.value }
      });
      tempCurrent=discussionGroups.data;
    } catch (err) { setError(err.response.data) };

      tempStudent.map((studentElement, index) => {
        //reset room to waiting before updating rooms based on DB
        tempStudent[index].room = '/waiting';
        tempCurrent.map((currentElement) => {
          let matchedId = currentElement.userIds.filter(f => f === studentElement.id).toString()
          if (matchedId === studentElement.id) {
            tempStudent[index].room = currentElement.groupNumber
          };
        });
      });

      setStudentInfo(tempStudent);
      setCurrentConfig(tempCurrent);
  };

  const createSeatingConfig = async () => {
    Promise.all(groups.map(async index => {
      try {
        await axios.post('/api/discussionGroups/configurations/create', {
          groupNumber: index,
          userIds: [],
          configuration: textboxValue
        });
      } catch (err) { setError(err.response.data) };
    }));

    try { 
      const res = await axios.get('/api/discussionGroups/configurations');
      setSeatingConfig(res.data)
    } catch (err) { setError(err.response.data) };

    //This part isn't causing config select to render on change

    // const syntheticEvent = {
    //   bubbles: true,
    //   target: {
    //     value: textboxValue
    //   }
    // }
    
    // handleChangeConfig(syntheticEvent);
    handleConfigModalClose();
  };
```

Passing the e.target.value as a synthetic event is not triggering a render of the select component, and I'm a bit lost as to how to fix that.

-Cheers!